# Could you paraphrase sentence number two

Tags: word-meaning

> 1. In order to rent an apartment in California or Texas, how much credit is needed when you do not want to have a co signer?
> 2. Better your credit, the eaiser your chances are. 700+ is good credit. 650+ is ok. 600--- you have problems paying bills or are overextended.

Because I connot understand what **overextended** really mean in this context.

Comment: The author of that text incorrectly separated a single word into two.  [overextend](https://www.google.com/search?site=&source=hp&q=overextended&oq=overextended&gs_l=hp.3..0l5j0i10j0j0i10l3.530.2137.0.3276.13.12.0.1.1.1.263.1723.0j5j4.9.0.msedr...0...1c.1.61.hp..5.8.1376.0.Y7V65DVFNAc)  There are multiple meanings, figurative and literal, for the word; they all refer to stretching something beyond the point it was meant to be stretched.  Specifically one's finances in this case.

Comment: @JasonPatterson That should probably be an answer (or _the_ answer) since it says everything that needs to be said!

Answer (score 1):

As Jason Patterson said in the comments, to "over-extend" (whether two words, one, or a hyphenated word) is to stretch something further than it was meant to be stretched, and now it's flimsy. If you over-extend your arm, you can strain muscles, and you certainly can't lift anything of any weight with it. If you over-extend your finances, you are having trouble paying for things because you are spending nearly exactly your income or more (with an implication of frivolity, or carelessness).

What that sentence is saying that if your credit rating is 600 or lower, you are considered likely to be unable to pay back a house-loan, because your finances are already over-extended. You're already paying out too much money. You're a poor credit risk for the companies.